# Ode to Regular Expressions

Tags: lateral-thinking, computer-puzzle

Robert loves [regular expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) and ever since his friend Jean introduced him to [Regex Golf](https://xkcd.com/1313/), he spends most of his time trying to find the shortest and most elegant solution possible. Robert is also very well-organized and likes to keep an archive containing all his regular expressions along with the test cases accompanying them.

For example `[^ad]+` is his neuest regex. It matches the titles from every book in the Lord of the Rings trilogy:

- The Fellowship of the Ring
- The Two Towers
- The Return of the King

and none from the *A Song of Ice and Fire* series:

- A Game of Thrones
- A Clash of Kings
- A Storm of Swords
- A Feast for Crows
- A Dance with Dragons
- The Winds of Winter
- A Dream of Spring

However, he just noticed that he is missing the test case for his very first (and admittedly messy) regular expression:

```
Au.+|B[eu].+[ma]|C.+|D.+|E.+|F.+|G.+|H.+|I[rt].+|L.[tx].+|Mal.+|N.+s|P.+|Ro.+|Sl.+|S.[ae].+|(Un.+)?
```

Robert being the perfectionist he is desperately wants to remember what this monstrosity was even supposed to match, can you help him?

Comment: The Lord of the Rings is actually 3 volumes with 2 books in each. The titles you have listed are the titles of the volumes. #pedantic

Comment: @IanMacDonald I just checked on my bookshelf and it turns out you are right. Though to be fair, it is easy to be overlooked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this regular expression matches ...

> ... the members of the European Union in a list of all European countries.

Explanation:

> The vertical bar denotes alternatives, so if any of the patterns between bars match, the whole expression matches:
>
>  `Au.+` → Austria
>  `B[eu].+[ma]` → Belgium, Bulgaria
>  `C.+` → Croatia, Cyprus, Czech Republic
>  `D.+` → Denmark
>  `E.+` → Estonia
>  `F.+` → Finland, France
>  `G.+` → Germany, Greece
>  `H.+` → Hungary
>  `I[rt].+` → Ireland, Italy
>  `L.[tx].+` → Latvia, Lithuania, Luxembourg
>  `Mal.+` → Malta
>  `N.+s` → Netherlands
>  `P.+` → Poland, Portugal
>  `Ro.+` → Romania
>  `Sl.+` → Slovakia
>  `S.[ae].+` → Spain, Sweden
>  `(Un.+)?` → United Kingdom
>
>  Simple patterns like `E.+` mean there is no ambiguity. More complex patterns must select EU members over non-EU members, e.g. none of the `S` pattern matches Switzerland.

Comment: Australia and Canada are both included, though.

Comment: Yes, but that's not a European country.

Comment: Define "European country". Both of those are members of the British commonwealth. ;)

Comment: Aristotelian physics say that a country that is even its own bloody continent can't be European. `:)`

Comment: And the typo hint, neuest gives n**EU**est